# wifi networks don't show up in network manager

Tags: debian, wifi, networkmanager, iwlwifi, backports

I have installed the iwlwifi driver from backports for my intel wifi card
here is the output of the `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` :

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a370] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

here are all the steps up to installing the iwlwifi driver

```
apt install -t stretch-backports linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64
apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4
sudo make install
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
reboot
```

The wifi interface is visible in `ip a` and after I bring it up and run `iwlist wlp0s20f3 scan` it is able to do the scanning fine, but the wifi icon in the toolbar is not showing any networks even after a `sudo service network-manager restart`. What could be the reason for this behavior?